# for each List lastname and people they supervise, include All employees must be listed (even those who do not supervise anyone)

Tags: postgresql

order by most number of employees supervised, then by last name.

```
 SELECT Lname,COUNT(*)
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE Ssn=Super_ssn IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY Super_ssn,lname
```

The problem here is, I am not sure about what to include in WHERE to actually count those ssn

Example setup: 
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xhEj2sAgdTMABBkCtJvmoC/0#&togetherjs=z3CKywAccH

Comment: So what is your expected output?

Comment: `order by 2,1`?

Comment: Please post the schema, sample data and expected output. See [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).